# IBM appid, nodejs app error {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"redirect_uri doesn\\'t belongs to the clientID"}

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

Recently I created IBM APPID service and download nodejs code from service dash board and deployed on IBM cloud. As per instruction in dashboard it should work with default settings and no need to do additional setting in identity providers
But when I clicked on login but it gives me below error on redirect

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"redirect_uri doesn\'t belongs to the clientID"}

Not sure but is it something to do with redirect URL on identity providers-> manage page or something else
My understanding is that I downloaded nodejs code is from APPid service and it should work with default configuration of service 
[Manage page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IoZ1.png)

App.js code

```
 const LOGIN_URL = "/ibm/bluemix/appid/login";
 const CALLBACK_URL = "/ibm/bluemix/appid/callback";
```

Comment: Now I deleted that ibm user, then will it go to default page on log-in button clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Have you clicked on the edit button and insert facebook\google App id\Client ID or password?
If you did so you aren't using default configuration anymore and need to follow the instructions of adding appid's redirect URL to facebooke\google and add your redirect to appid in the lower box

Comment: Now I deleted that ibm user, then will it go to default page on log-in button clicked?